# How to go next/previous highlighted member in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

When you set caret on member/method in code you have all its occurrences highlighted, what is a shortcut to navigate through them? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Edit` | `Find` | **Find Next** and **Find Previous** (<kbd>F3</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> on Windows keymap). Note that you need to highlight the occurrences explicitly first (`Edit` | `Find` | **Highlight Usages in File**).