# How to go to next/previous member fields in IntelliJ, similar to the ReSharper feature

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

It's  about something similar to the ReSharper feature "[Go to Next/Previous Member](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Next_Previous_Member.html)", but inside IntelliJ (not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120851/how-to-go-next-previous-highlighted-member-in-intellij) similarly named question)

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> in IntellJ is by default mapped to "Previous/Next Method", so it skips member variables, whereas ReSharper maps that to "Next/Previous Member", which obviously steps over everything, including fields and properties.

Is there any solution for IntelliJ to mimic ReSharper's feature, perhaps through a plugin or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has been implemented and reverted because of negative feedback (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107538).

This behavior can still be turned on by adding to "Help | Edit custom VM options":

```
-Dide.structural.navigation.visit.fields=true
```

Comment: is there any way to have these behaviors in parallel, i.e. a key combination for the method-only version and another key combination for the other one?